# GMSMapView didTapAtCoordinate gives wrong coordinates until map is panned

Tags: ios, google-maps, uitableview, uigesturerecognizer

I am working with a GMSMapView that I have added as a custom UITableViewCell. When I first create the map and capture an initial user tap, my coordinates are based as though the user tapped near lat/lon 0/0 -- I get values like -1.800144/-1.867676 even though my map center is set to 43.50 and -116.22 (and the map displays around those coordinates).

However, when I move the map by panning it once, and then tapping on it, my coordinates are more along the line of what I expect. Also, if I add the following code to the GMSMapViewDelegate method mapView:idleAtCameraPosition: I get the correct coordinates the first time:

```
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken ;
dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
    GMSCameraUpdate *update = [GMSCameraUpdate setCamera:position] ;
    [mapView moveCamera:update] ;
}) ;
```

But that seems like a hack that is hiding a more fundamental issue.

Here is the relevant code:

My custom table view cell creates the initial mapView in its constructor:

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        // Camera position is moot, just need something to instantiate the map view
        GMSCameraPosition * cameraPosition = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:0 longitude:0 zoom:5];

        GMSMapView * mapView = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:CGRectZero camera:cameraPosition];

        _mapView = mapView ;
     }
    return self;
}
```

In my view controller, I set the gestures enabled, set my delegate and my map bounds:

```
- (void) configureMap
{
    [_mapView.settings setAllGesturesEnabled:YES];
    [_mapView.settings setConsumesGesturesInView:YES] ;

    _mapView.delegate = self ;

    // _userTrip has among other things, a bounds for our map
    GMSCoordinateBounds * bounds = _userTrip.bounds ;

    DDLogInfo(@"Trip Bounds are sw(%f:%f) ne(%f:%f)",   bounds.southWest.latitude, bounds.southWest.longitude, bounds.northEast.latitude, bounds.northEast.longitude) ;

    GMSCameraUpdate *cameraUpdate = [GMSCameraUpdate fitBounds:bounds];
    [_mapView moveCamera:cameraUpdate];
}
```

My delegate for camera position:

```
- (void) mapView:(GMSMapView *)mapView idleAtCameraPosition:(GMSCameraPosition *)position
{
    DDLogInfo(@"User changed map size. Zoom is now set to %f", mapView.camera.zoom) ;
    /* putting this in 'fixes' the problem
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken ;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        GMSCameraUpdate *update = [GMSCameraUpdate setCamera:position] ;
        [mapView moveCamera:update] ;
    }) ;
     */
 }
```

My delegate method for taps:

```
- (void) mapView:(GMSMapView *)mapView didTapAtCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)coordinate
{
    DDLogInfo(@"User did tap at coordinate %f, %f", coordinate.latitude, coordinate.longitude) ;
    DDLogInfo(@"Map view center %f %f and zoom is %f",  mapView.camera.target.latitude, mapView.camera.target.longitude, mapView.camera.zoom) ;
}
```

Sample output:

```
[] Trip Bounds are sw(43.409890:-116.435511) ne(43.597180:-116.023860)

[] map view zoom = 10.053131

[] User changed map size. Zoom is now set to 10.053131

--- At this point, the map is displayed and it shows the right location based on the bounds in the log statement above. Then, when I tap on the map:

[] User did tap at coordinate -0.262352, -0.900879

[] Map view center 43.503608 -116.229685 and zoom is 10.053131

--- As you can see above, the user coordinates are way off based on where the map thinks it is. Below, I have panned the map and then did another tap

[] User changed map size. Zoom is now set to 10.053131

[] User did tap at coordinate 43.447926, -116.340871

[] Map view center 43.426753 -116.377271 and zoom is 10.053131
```

As you can see, the user coordinates now appear to be a valid location on the map. I have verified through the debugger that the same map instance is being referenced throughout and it has the same gestureRecognizer.

I had a previous version of the same code that did not put the GMSMapView inside a table view cell, and it does not exhibit the same problem. So, I suspect there is an initialization issue caused by putting this in a UITableViewCell.

Anyone run across something like this and have any idea how to fix it?

Comment: The 'fix' that seems to work is to move where the construction of the GMSMapView takes place into the viewWillAppear method rather than init. For whatever reason, the gesture recognizers are not in sync with the map unless you construct it there.